# Send file from HTML form to AWS S3 Bucket

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I'm taking the file from a html form and then uploading it to an AWS S3 bucket.

The following code finds the path of the file **on my computer** and then uploads it to S3:

```php
$bucketname = 'we-sign-files';
$file_path = '/Users/dripz/Desktop/wesign/uploads/5f31fc30410c17.68431957.jpg';
$key = basename($file_path);

try {
    $s3->putObject([
        'Bucket' => $bucketname,
        'Key'    => $key,
        'Body'   => fopen($file_path, 'r')
    ]);
} catch (Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

What code should I put in the `$file_path =`  variable to take the image from the **users' computer** and then upload to S3?

Comment: After uploading, by [`$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php)

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Not sure I'm understanding?

Comment: ok, files on a users computer is not accessible to the server (if it were imagine the security implications), you have to upload the file first, then once its uploaded you can then push to the s3. The link above should help you with the uploading, or you can search `upload file php` on [enter search engine here] which will yield lots of solutions.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thanks! However, I'm still confused as to where the file is "uploaded" if it is pushed to s3 after. Can you please clarify?

Comment: unless you use move_uploaded_file() function, it will be in `/tmp` till garbage collection or restart. The $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] pointed out above would have a path to the file i.e `/tmp/thefile.abc123.tmp`, you then use $_FILES['file']['name'] for its name etc.. you dont have to save the file anywhere before pushing to s3

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I'm using the move_upload_file() function. So would I add /tmp/thefile.abc123.tmp to the second argument in the move_upload_file() function?

Answer (score 0):

Use file_get_contents:
file_get_contents($_FILES['uploadedfileFormField']['tmp_name']);

and then you don't need: **fopen**.
Try-catch and error handling you have to take care of.

```
$bucketname = 'we-sign-files';
$fileName = $_FILES['uploadedfileFormField']['tmp_name']; 
$file_path = file_get_contents($fileName);
$key = basename($fileName);

try {
    $s3->putObject([
        'Bucket' => $bucketname,
        'Key'    => $key,
        'Body'   => $file_path
    ]);
} catch (Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: So the file_get_contents method will grab the file. But what code do I use inside of the variable to grab the file from the html form?

Comment: I read this in your question:
"to take the image from the user's computer" form was not mentioned in this question

Comment: what is field name or share code of your form field, please

Comment: It was, and there has been no edits.. also you left in fopen

Comment: @LawrenceCherone tell me the field name of type=file, i will modify the code

Comment: provide html form field + your method should be POST